# How to prove: $\cot(A/2)/(s−a)=\cot(B/2)/(s−b)=\cot(C/2)/(s−c)=1/r$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

i want the geometrical proof of this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think many people want to guess how your variables are defined. "Guess what is my homework and do it for me"?

Comment: Can you show us what attempts you have made on solving this problem?

Comment: What is $s$, $r$, and what have you tried?

Comment: $s,r$ are the semi-perimeter and radius of the inscribed circle in $\triangle ABC$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $O$ be the center of the inscribed circle of $\triangle ABC$, and let $A', B', C'$ be the points on $BC, CA, AB$ where the circle meets the sides, observe that: $AB' = AC', BA' = BC', CA' = CB', 2AB' + 2BC' + 2CA' = a+b+c \implies AB' = \dfrac{a+b+c}{2} - (BC'+CA') = s - a$, and $r = OB'$. Thus $\cot\left(\frac{A}{2}\right) = \dfrac{AB'}{OB'} = \dfrac{s-a}{r}$, which is the desire claim.

Comment: Very nice: +1 ${}{}$